# MySQL Update issue with log IP address using CONCAT()

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating simple star rating system now things are working fine but when it comes to update IP address it's giving me such a pain now..

I have created table using this query

```
return 'CREATE TABLE star_ratings ('.
    'id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,'.
    'post_id INT (11),'.
    'rating FLOAT (11) DEFAULT 0,'.
    'total_rating FLOAT (11) DEFAULT 0,'.
    'total_rates INT (11) DEFAULT 0,'.
    'ipaddress LONGTEXT'.
');
```

Check the IP Address column in image

[image]

Now trying to update it using `CONCAT()` but it is not adding any value. And to debug when I tried to update without `CONCAT()` than it's updating the value. I just wonder what this is not working and where I am wrong.

Other thing if you notice in `ipaddress` column I am getting weird `ipaddress` `::1` instead of something like `127.1.1.1`

Here is my update query

```
UPDATE star_ratings 
SET rating = '$rating', 
total_rating = '$total_rating', 
total_rates = '$total_rates', 
ipaddress = CONCAT(ipaddress, ',$ipaddress')

WHERE post_id = '$post_id'
```

Comment: `::1` is the IPV6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1. Where does `$ipaddress` come from in your example?

Comment: I am working on localhost.. I mean dev environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the update is failing when to append ipaddress when the field is null to start with, in which case ...

```
UPDATE star_ratings 
SET rating = '$rating', 
total_rating = '$total_rating', 
total_rates = '$total_rates', 
ipaddress = CONCAT(ifnull(ipaddress,''), ',$ipaddress')
```

concat will return null if any part is null ( null propogation ) so the following will yield null

```
select concat(null, 'hello')
```

the [ifnull() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) will replace a null first param with the second param

```
select ifnull(null,'hello') => 'hello'
```

and

```
select ifnull('hi','hello') => 'hi'
```

Comment: This is cool solve the issue... just for knowledge can you please explain the difference?

Answer (score 2):

On windows7 localhost resolves to `::1` (you can try pinging in cmd). If you access your page over `localhost/somepage.php` try it over `127.0.0.1/somepage.php`.

Comment: You are welcome. Figured it out only yesterday and that's probably why it rang a bell! =)

Answer (score 1):

Use function `CONCAT_WS(' ',field1,field2)` in place of `CONCAT()`..